# Angular 2 model property not picking up the updated date value from Kendo UI Date Picker

Tags: angularjs, typescript, kendo-datepicker

I am writing an angular application where in I want to call the API on the basis of updated value of the Kendo Date Picker. Kendo Date Picker is bound to the Angular Model However, after changing the date, I get the same old value (initially assigned value) in the model variable. Following is the Typescript and HTML code I am using. Am I missing anything ?

HTML:

```
 <input id="datepicker"  kendo-datepicker k-ng-model="StartDate" value="{{StartDate}}" />
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save();">Save</button>
```

Code:

```
export class AdminPeriodConfigurationComponent {
    StartDate: any;
    constructor(private _router: Router, private _globalService: GlobalService){
    }

    loadData(){
       this.StartDate="09/28/2016";// format is "mm-dd-yyyy" and this value binds to datepicker
    }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.loadData();
    }

    save(){
       var myobj=new MyClass();
       myobj.NewSelectedDate=this.StartDate; // here the updated value does not get assigned.
    }
}
```